# Latest intellij community edition git revert disabled

Tags: intellij-idea

Git rollback/revert is disabled in my git repo. I Google and found this:-

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000260784-Enable-Disable-preserving-project-state-when-switching-between-Git-branches

But it did't help me. Pls check attached pic

[image]

[image]

As you can see file is modifed but git revert is disable. How can I enable it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "As you can see file is modified", because if it was modified (according to git) the name of the file would be blue and you'd get a [green or blue block in the gutter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html#editor) for each added or modified line. Are you sure git is set up correctly?

Comment: You can see see in the attached pic in the terminal git status is showing 3 modified files. That maens git repo is correctly done and works fine from the terminal. But for some reason intellij disabled revert option.

Comment: The terminal in IntelliJ is a regular terminal, which is completely independent of how you configure git in the IJ project. You could cd to a directory of a different git repo and `git status` will show you the changes of that repo. Is your remote configured when you go to **Git > Manage remotes...**?

Comment: Well any other terminal shows same output. Perhpas I found the reason. I posted as an answer. Hopefully, it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Since the color of a filename hasn't changed it seems that you don't have version control setup in IDE.
Could you please go to Preferences | Version Control | Directory Mappings and see if you have correct path there?
Also please make sure that git is detected correctly under Preferences | Version Control | Git (Press Test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git repo credential needs to setup in order to let Intellij know the git repo status. I did this

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

After this all is fine. Maybe this only needed in windwos.